# Clarinet Joints Loose After Left Assembled

Tags: instruments, maintenance, woodwinds, clarinet

So I was careless and after playing left my clarinet assembled on a stand for about 2 weeks while I went on vacation. When I took it apart I noticed the joints were loose. Any way I can fix this or will I have to get them all replaced? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 2):

If by "loose" you mean the corks are overcompressed so the body parts wobble, then the corks may recover after you leave the clarinet disassembled for a couple days (and maybe gently hydrate the corks).
If you mean the corks themselves came loose, then they need to be replaced.

That said,  I find it rather unusual that the joints' fit would go bad whether or not the clarinet was left assembled.  Was this during winter months (very low humidity)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the joints got over compressed. This was during summer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if the corks are dried out and/or over-compressed.  A little time dis-assembled and a touch of cork grease (Vaseline will do) should fix it.